# Wildcard search in neo4j using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I wanted to use wildcard search on Username. when i run the below query I'm not able to get the user information. (Username='VivianPai')
Query

```
match (u:User)
where u.Name= 'Vivia.*'
return u;
```

Is it like in order to do the wildcard search do we need to Index on the User field.If yes, how can I do the wild card search without creating Index?

Thanks

Comment: To perform a regex search you would use `=~ 'Vivia.*'`, this is pretty well documented.

Comment: One more query, how can i use wildcard search for relationship types? Query is --> `match path= (u:User)-[:HAS]->()
where u.Name =~'Vivia.*'
return path`. how can i use wildcard for HAS?

Comment: That is another question again. (u:User)-[r]->() WHERE type(r) =~"HA.*

Comment: @ johnmark, thank you. How can i do this in the 1st query you suggested. `match (u:User)
where u.Name =~ '*.via.*'
return u`. But the query is not working

Comment: I got it. the query is `where u.Name =~'.*Vivia.*'`

Comment: for wildcard search on nodes I'd use a lucene legacy index which will be faster, see: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/